# Google Images API's execute_transforms() returning "there has been an error"

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use Google's Image Manipulation API. It seems pretty straightforward, but when I call `execute_transforms` on the `Image` object, it throws a generic "There has been an error"

The `gcs_file_location` is correct, no errors get thrown until I call execute_transforms(). The image file is not too large.

```py
from google.appengine.api import images


gcs_file_location = '/gs/' + gcs_file_location
img = images.Image(filename=gcs_file_location)
img.resize(width=50, height=50)

# The following code throws "There has been an error"
thumbnail = img.execute_transforms()
```

Comment: I made a test with the same code but reading from a local image, the function `img.execute_transforms()` did not raise that generic "There has been an error", so check that the image is correctly read and the `img` type is `<class 'google.appengine.api.images.Image'>`. Also search in the logs for that error, probably there is a more specific stacktrace of the error there.

Comment: It does indeed have type <class 'google.appengine.api.images.Image'>, and there is no error message logged in App Engine's Logs either!

Comment: I replicated your error using the official documentation [example code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/images/api/main.py). From that code I just modified it in order to get as http parameter (`id`) the image path (`/gs/<bucket name>/<img path>`), then i deployed and it worked correctly. Could you please write the precise steps that you are taking in order to see that error, also, would be great to see the entire code in order to reproduce your error, thanks.

Comment: One difference is that I'm using Django for the backend web framework. Is django not compatible with Google's Imaging API or do I need to import WebApp2?

Other than that, all the relevant code is shown above, and I'm fairly certain the GS path is correct, it's formatted like this: /gs/371/3612ae-63163s-3.

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while but I managed to replicate your scenario, so I set up a **Python 2.7** environment (according to the tutorial for the [Images Python API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/) and set all the files needed for Django using the code from the [official repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/django) and running it with the help of the [official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) for Django.

Then, I modified the service polls in order to execute the functions that are raising those errors.

```py
def index(request):
    filename_gs=request.GET.get("id")
    img = images.Image(filename=filename_gs)
    img.resize(width=1000, height=1000)
    thumbnail = img.execute_transforms()
```

And I found that indeed you are right, in the function `execute_transforms` raises and error and stops the execution. However, I did not have the generic error that you are referring to, I'm getting the following:

```py
  File "/home/polortiz/DJANGOOO/mytry3/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/django/polls/views.py", line 48, in index
    thumbnail = img.execute_transforms()
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 810, in execute_transforms
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 615, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 898, in execute_transforms_hook
    raise _ToImagesError(e, self._blob_key)
TransformationError
```

I investigated further in order to check which could be the problems that raises those errors, and found the [library code of that function](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/images#Image.execute_transforms). There you could see all the exception that raises:

> - BadRequestError: When the request specifications are invalid.
> - NotImageError: When the image data given is not an image.
> - BadImageError: When the image data given is corrupt.
> - LargeImageError: When the image data given is too large to process.
> - InvalidBlobKeyError: When the blob key provided is invalid.
> - TransformationError: When an error occurs during image manipulation.
> - AccessDeniedError: When the blob key refers to a Google Storage object, and the application does not have permission to access the object.
> - ObjectNotFoundError: When the blob key refers to an object that no longer exists.

So, in order to solve your problem would be great to check all those points. Answering to the questions asked on the comments:

> Is django not compatible with Google's Imaging API or do I need to import WebApp2?

Google's Imaging API is compatible with Django. And it is not mandatory to use WebApp2 in order to handle http requests and responses.

Comment: Thanks Pol, I ultimately ended up using Python Image Library to do image manipulations as I just wasn't able to get it to work. 

It's likely the same Transformation Error that you got, which is still a pretty generic error. 

I'll accept your answer, if you ever figure out what exactly is happening, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this problem recently too when using `get_serving_url()` on image files in a GCS bucket *which has granular permissions disabled*.  For some reason, it seems that the Images API throws a `TransformationError` on such a bucket even though no transformation is happening.  [Here's a bug opened with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148634961) which notes one has to make a new bucket and be sure to use granular permissions in order to avoid the error.